# Black screen in Adobe AIR App for iOS 8

Tags: ipad, flash, air, ios8, flashdevelop

I have an App for iPad two years working fine. But now after updating to iOS8 the App only shows a black screen.

The App was made with Flashdevelop.

I tried compiling the App with the newest Adobe AIR SDK (15), but the result is the same.

Are more changes needed?

Thanks.

Comment: You really need to give us more details if you expect an answer. I guess you are a developer, so if I tell you my computer is not working would you be able to tell me the exact problem ?

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu, The App was working a week ago, so I don't know where the App is crashing now. I'm posting here looking for someone who had the same behavior. If I found something more concrete, I could be more explicit.

Comment: Have you tried to run the app in the "desktop" AIR simulator ? Maybe it is an AIR issue and not an iOS 8 problem. I would start with this. Also Could you maybe still test on a device with iOS7 What is the App name. I could give it a try on one of my test devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the very latest SDK (`15.0.0.289`) from labs.adobe.com.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the last SDK for this. Finally I solved the problem, creating a new project from the last Flashdevelop template and it works. Thanks.